# Javascript fails in WP-Admin after update

Tags: wordpress, templates, admin

I have a wordpress website with a custom theme. Now when I upgrade that wordpress install to 3.3.1 it looks like the javascript is nog working correctly. All pop-ups (like adding image) and functions (like collapsing boxes or opening screen options) don't work. Also the admin bar doesn't show anymore

What could the problem be? It worked fine in older wordpress website's (3.2 and less)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a few months I finally found my answer (I stopped looking for a while). Turns out I had this error:

Call to undefined method Custom_Admin_Bar::add_group()

The theme contains a Custom_Admin_Bar (in classes.php) and that was causing the error because it didn't had the method add_group().

I removed the Custom_Admin_Bar and then it worked perfectly.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-to-undefined-method-custom_admin_baradd_group

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with 3.3.1, which was fixed by adding this to wp-config.php
`define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);`

If that fails, check out the Troubleshooting WordPress 3.3 Master List: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-33-master-list

Comment: Thank you for posting this fix, was driving me crazy for weeks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem appear suddenly in wordpress as well, it turned out that JQuery and a few other js files were being loaded twice(in the header and in the footer).